# trouble with jQuery cookie in Drupal 7

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm trying to write a PHP script that launches a colorbox window when a user attempts to leave the page. Using jQuery Cookie, it's supposed to launch just once per visit. However, with the cookie code in place, the colorbox isn't launching, but when I remove those statements, the colorbox launches. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
drupal_add_js('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js','external');
drupal_add_js('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js','external');
drupal_add_js('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.colorbox/1.6.3/jquery.colorbox-min.js','external');
drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        jQuery(".iframe").colorbox({
          iframe:true, 
          width: 850,
          height: 700,
            });

});','inline');       

drupal_add_js(jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(document).mousemove(function(e) {
            if (e.pageY <= 5) {
              if (jQuery(.cookie('pop') === undefined)) {             
                jQuery("#colorbox").click();
                jQuery(.cookie('pop', '1' ));
            }
        }
    });
});,'inline');
?>

<p><a id="colorbox" class="iframe" href="http://www.bing.com"></a></p>
```

Comment: `jQuery(.cookie('pop', '1' ));` looks wrong. Try `jQuery.cookie('pop', '1' );`

Comment: Also, I just discovered that the jQuery Cookie isn't getting loaded. I'm not sure why.

Comment: Instead of `if (jQuery(.cookie('pop') === undefined))` try `if (jQuery.cookie('pop') == undefined)`

Comment: Have you ever looked in your browser console for debugging?

Comment: There is an issue where someone is asking about jQuery cookie not being loaded https://www.drupal.org/node/2596001

Comment: @Huelfe: Yes. I realized that the library wasn't getting loaded after I typing in "jQuery.cookie" in the console, seeing nothing returned, and checking the page source in the browser.

Comment: @cilefen: Yes, but it wasn't particularly helpful. Thank you, though.